# Johansen test shows r=2 but 3 cointegration vectors are estimated

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, cointegration

I try to interpret the output of the code below: a Johansen cointegration test of three variables.

The test results indicate there are 2 cointegration relationship (r<=2).

The test outputs also show a matrix for 3 cointegration vectors, although the test results show r<=2. I understand that the r=2 is determined but is not imposed, so we see three vectors estimated.

My questions are:
What is interpretation of these three columns?

Are they all proper long-run relationships? (but then it would conflict with the test result that r<=2)

If not, is the third column the least appropriate cointegration vector, give the eigenvalue is the smallest among the three?

```
library(urca) 
set.seed (12345)
e1 <- rnorm (250 , 0 , 0.5 ) 
e2 <- rnorm (250 , 0 , 0.5 ) 
e3 <- rnorm (250 , 0 , 0.5 )
u1.ar1 <- arima.sim (model = list ( ar = 0.75 ) , innov = e1 , n = 250) 
u2.ar1 <- arima.sim (model = list ( ar = 0.3 ) , innov = e2 , n = 250) 
y3 <- cumsum( e3 ) 
y1 <- 0.8 * y3 + u1.ar1 
y2 <- -0.3 * y3 + u2.ar1 
y.mat <- data.frame ( y1 , y2 , y3 ) 
vecm <- ca.jo (y.mat)
jo.results <- summary (vecm) ;jo.results
```

## Test Results

```
Eigenvalues (lambda):
[1] 0.27036 0.15474 0.01884
Values of teststatistic and critical values of test:

      test 10pct  5pct  1pct

r <= 2 |  4.72  6.50  8.18 11.65
r <= 1 | 41.69 12.91 14.90 19.19
r = 0  | 78.17 18.90 21.07 25.75
```

## Cointegration vectors

```
Eigenvectors, normalised to first column:
(These are the cointegration relations)

                   y1.l2               y2.l2              y3.l2
y1.l2  1.000000000000000  1.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000
y2.l2 -4.732435772888009  0.2273774352823677 0.1513857569909009
y3.l2 -2.129850289981805 -0.6657324440064055 2.3153223572629686
```

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test is estimating whether the eigenvalues are significantly different from 0.  The first test has the null hypothesis that largest eigenvalue is 0 (equivalent to whether r=0), then the second largest, and so on.

Your results tell you the third eigenvalue is not significantly different from 0, so you should ignore the associated third eigenvector.

Just so you are aware, 3 cointegrating relationships for 3 integrated data series is not a real thing.  If you can write n cointegrating relationships for n series, then you can combine those relationships to get scalar multiples of the original series on their own, implying they were already stationary.

Comment: what if the highest eigenvalue is not significantly lower than 0 (so we stop the steps), but the lowest eigenvalue is significantly higher than 0? We still asume that there is no cointegration relationship?